# Set Picture into RemoteViews

Tags: android, svg, bitmap, imageview, drawable

I have some SVGs in my assets folder and I need to dynamically set them in my widget (on an ImageView).

I am using this library: http://code.google.com/p/svg-android/

This library returns a Picture or a PictureDrawable.

The only methods I can see to use on RemoteViews are setImageViewBitmap which obviously takes a bitmap.

I tried looking for code to convert a Drawable to a Bitmap like this:

```
PictureDrawable pictureDrawable = svg.createPictureDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(pictureDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), pictureDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888); 
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap); 
canvas.drawPicture(pictureDrawable.getPicture()); 
currentBitmap = bitmap;
```

But the bitmap is too small. When I create the bitmap in Illustrator I set the artboard size to 65 which is what comes through on the intrinsic width/height.

My widgets can be resized so the ImageView sizes are variable. Even if I set the width and height statically to some large number like this...

```
 Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(300, 300, Config.ARGB_8888);
```

then the resulting bitmap just has a bunch of whitespace below and to the right of a tiny image.

I guess I need to somehow draw the picture at a scaled up value as well as creating the Bitmap at size 300. Ideally I could figure out the size of the ImageView at runtime and set the proper sized Bitmap if I knew that. Is this the best approach and how would I do this? Perhaps there is a better approach I don't even know about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up modifying the underlying Artboard size to be 300. None of the scaling up methods worked. So the final code I used was that which I originally posted:

```
PictureDrawable pictureDrawable = svg.createPictureDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(pictureDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), pictureDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888); 
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap); 
canvas.drawPicture(pictureDrawable.getPicture()); 
currentBitmap = bitmap;
```

Once I had a 300x300 Bitmap I was able to set it into the RemoteViews using setImageViewBitmap .

This kind of defeated the purpose of using SVGs in the first place (at least as far as using them in widgets was concerned).

My problem was not the same as User117. Perhaps he did not name the outer layer 'bounds' as was required in the library. Either way, I managed to get the library working, albeit by having to modify the SVG Artboard size.

Hopefully with the increase in screen resolution Android will introduce SVGs as part of the platform soon.

Comment: Hi, I have seen your pocket app and it's very good to use. Is that code an opensource?

Answer (score 4):

I've not used `android-svg` but if it's using vanilla `PictureDrawable`s, then it should be just a matter of not using the intrinsic bounds.

Try the following:

```
PictureDrawable pictureDrawable = svg.createPictureDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(300, 300, Config.ARGB_8888); 
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap); 
pictureDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
pictureDrawable.draw(canvas); // do not access the Picture directly, that defeats the purpose
currentBitmap = bitmap;
```

In short, use the Drawable, not its Picture and set the Drawable's bounds to be the full canvas.

Comment: Good points thanks. Would I have to just take some randomly large size like 300 and then let the ImageView on the RemoteViews scale the bitmap size down? Is there no better way to set and svg into a ImageView for a widget?

Comment: Well, an `ImageView` takes ownership of the Bitmap and will rescale it as it sees fit. 

That said, if you want to avoid rescaling (and your hierarchy is already inflated), use `ImageView.getMeasuredWidth()` (and *Height()) to get the View's dimensions and render an appropriately sized SVG. Further, set `scaleType` to `fitXY` to avoid resampling.

Comment: I tried the code you provided but the icon was not scaled up to 300px. Instead there was just a lot more white space and a tiny icon in the top left corner.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried createScaledBitmap?

[createScaledBitmap()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29)

Comment: I imagine his purpose behind using `android-svg` is to avoid blurry rasterizations :)

Comment: you make a good point.

I'd imagine he could scale (not sure if even scale is the correct term.. since it's practically vector) up the SVG using that library as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried `svg-android` and it has not worked for me for this very reason. Not to mention its severely limited feature set.

The point of using vector graphics is that I can generate images of any appropriate size to fit the UI View size. Which means the generation method must accept the size requirements at run-time, and not always use `width`,`height` declared in `<svg>` tag.

Hence I [used](https://bitbucket.org/zedvoid/indico/src) the native implementation: [`libsvg-android`](https://launchpad.net/libsvg-android), which exactly does that.

It directly renders to a canvas with given size:

```
long objId = SvgRaster.svgAndroidCreate();
SvgRaster.svgAndroidParseBuffer(objId, readString(mInputStream, "UTF-8"));
SvgRaster.svgAndroidSetAntialiasing(objId, true);
SvgRaster.svgAndroidRenderToArea(objId, mCanvas, 0, 0, mWidth, mHeight);
```

Comment: I only had the problem for RemoteViews. Was this your experience too or were you unable to use it in normal ImageViews? I found this worked:    AssetManager am = c.getAssets();
   SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromAsset(am, path);
   PictureDrawable pictureDrawable = svg.createPictureDrawable();
   iconView.setImageDrawable(pictureDrawable);

Comment: @timothyjc yes `getPicture()` of `svg-android` has never worked for me. It never rendered anything, also You can't use all svg tags.  Someone did fork the repo, and improved these problems. But unfortunately I don't remember that fork repo's link now :( .

Comment: Drawing to a canvas unfortunately wont help me set draw an svg into a RemoteViews ImageView afaik.